# Convert SQL query XML -> JSON

Tags: mysql, sql, json, xml

I need to convert this query by using JSON_EXTRACT and not ExtractValue anymore (our tool has updated its storage format, not XML anymore but JSON).

Could you please help me to translate this part ?

```
"where pv.id = ExtractValue(cv2.textvalue, 'content/value')  order by 1;"
```

Full query :

```
" Select pv.vname, pv.id  from (
    Select cv.* from customfieldvalue cv  
     where cv.customfield = 10014
         and cv.issue = $issue.customfield_10506
      ) cv2 , projectversion pv
 where pv.id = ExtractValue(cv2.textvalue, 'content/value')  order by 1;"
```

Comment: It is not clear what is your database. Please specify.

Comment: MySQL database it is

Answer (score 0):

Solved : "where pv.id = REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(textvalue, '$.keys[0]'),'"','')  order by 1;"

Please note that obviously the part keys[0]'),'"',' is adapted to my environment.